# Don't report missing "Embedded Resources" as error in jMeter

Tags: jmeter

In a sample, I checked "Retrieve all Embedded Resources" but now my sample reports an error if a linked resource is missing (HTTP status 404 from the server).

Can I tell my sample to retrieve the embedded resources but to ignore missing or problematic linked resources ? (so I can stop the unit only if a real functional problem occurs, and not when an image is missing)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can work it around using [JMeter Assertions](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#assertions)

1. Add a [Response Assertion](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Response_Assertion) as a child of the sampler which produces 404 code
2. Configure it as follows:

   - Apply to: check `Main sample and sub-samples`
   - Response fields to test: check `Ignore status`

[image: Response Assertion]

In this case erroneous statuses of mail sampler and its children will be ignored.

See [How to Use JMeter Assertions in 3 Easy Steps](http://blazemeter.com/blog/how-use-jmeter-assertions-3-easy-steps) for more information on pass/fail criteria definition via Assertions

Comment: It seems like this is still the best solution that is supported through the JMeter UI.  Is that correct?  Since I still care about the main sample's HTTP status, this doesn't quite do the trick for me.

Comment: What prevents you from using 2 assertions?

Comment: I was just trying to keep the number assertions to a minimum.  I have many samples and didn't want to unnecessarily create dozens of assertions for this purpose.

Answer (score 10):

One possibility is to edit `./bin/jmeter.properties` and set `httpsampler.ignore_failed_embedded_resources=true` as fixed by [Bug 44301](https://issues.apache.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=44301).

Comment: This looks great!  Is this still the best method for solving this problem?  I was hoping JMeter 3 would have addressed this through other means.